# where ODBC File DSN in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, registry

In Windows XP, 2003 there is one entry in the registry for ODBC file DNS location in the system:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC File DSN\DefaultDSNDir

Where can I get the default DSN folder in Windows Vista and/or Windows 2008

Thanks,

Comment: OK guys, I fixed it :-)
ODBC folder in Windows Vista/2008 is located in My Document folder, this is the default folder for it.

Answer (score 2):

The registry key you mentioned is put there by Microsoft Office. There is a per user version as well, in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\odbc.ini\ODBC File DSN\DefaultDSNDir`.
See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165866